# Avast not up to quality?

Tags: software-center, deb, malware, quality

When I follow this guide :http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-and-update-avast-antivirus-in-ubuntu#.UvRO9vgju1E

It says the .deb isn’t up quality code in the UbuntusoftwareCenter! I don't know to trust this guide or not! Help (someone who has done this!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that most of the thigs from UbuntuSoftwareCenter are woring ok. If there are some problems with the app you are trying to download you will see it in the comments. If the apps are good coded is other topic and you can't know that unless the software you are downloading is Open Source.

Comment: It isn’t in the softwarecenter the down file wants to install through the softwarecenter.